# Discrepancy with integral yielding arcsine of an expression

Tags: calculus, integration

In reviewing for a calc 2 test I have tomorrow, my friend and I got into an argument about the family of functions generating when evaluating the following antiderivative.

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-u^2x^2}}dx$$

I claimed that the solutions were of the following form:

$$\arcsin{\frac{ux}{a}}+C$$

My friend disagreed and said it was the following:

$$\frac{1}{u}\arcsin{\frac{ux}{a}}+C$$

I specifically remembered from calc 1 when my professor discussed inverse trig integrals that she said unlike with arcsecant and arctangent, we don't multiply arcsine by the scalar $\frac{1}{u}$.

I was surprised to find that referencing the online integral calculator I'm sure most of you are familiar with, it was giving an answer mirroring that of my friend. I decided to pull out my old textbook ("Calculus" 8th/9th edition by Larson Hostetler Edwards) and in the lesson on inverse trig integrals, the practice problems, and the integration tables in the appendices, it said that I was correct and my friend was wrong.

This is honestly very weird and I want to get things squared away. I feel like he will be correct but I'm on 6 hrs of sleep in the past 48 hours and can't bring myself to use the limit process with arcsine's Taylor series to find out cos my mind is taxed.

If someone could help me out I'd much appreciate it.

Comment: (non mathematical) advice : take a little rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: we have $$a^2-u^2x^2=u^2\left(\left(\frac{a}{u}\right)^2-x^2\right)$$